# Design patterns: Extract instance types into different buckets

Tags: design-patterns

I have the following type hierarchy:

```
interface I:
    ----+class B implements I
    ----+class C implements I
    ----+class D implements I
```

I have another class `Consumer1` that supports types `C` and `D` but not `B` (in its various methods) and a class `Consumer2` that supports type `B`. I have total control over `Consumer1` and `Consumer2` so I can choose how to implement them. Now, at runtime I expect my callers to give me a collection of `I`s and I will decide internally whether to route them to `Consumer1` or `Consumer2`.

Now, a very bad non-OOP way is to do an `if instanceof` check all over the place and mess things up. One alternative is to register a supporting class `Map<Class<?>, Class<?>>` that shall contain `{{B,Consumer2}, {C,Consumer1}, {D,Consumer1}}`. This is as bad as the previous one because I shall have to cast objects after figuring out whether to send them to `Consumer1` or `Consumer2`.

A second alternative is to apply a `Visitor` pattern which would solve this rather neatly but prevent my interface from being extended further (unless I modify the visitor). Is there a neater alternative?

Comment: It's really hard to follow this with all the B's, C's, D's, E's and F's.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Thanks. I gave them some meaningful names but the essence of the problem is that I want to filter a collection of objects based on what run time type they have.

Comment: Respectfully, if you have classes implementing an interface that require separate consumers, perhaps the interface should be split in two? Practically, maybe you can use Chain of Responsibility; `if(consumer1.canConsume(x)){ consumer1.consume(x); }else if(consumer2.canConsume(x)){ consumer2.consume(x); }`?

Comment: @John I entertained that possibility. But then how will canConsume() identify if it can consume a given type? Will it maintain a map of supported classes or use instanceof? I.e., the same problem again.

Comment: @MonsterTruck It could decide with a map, yes, or based on some properties of the interface, like which optional methods are implemented or the return value of boolean getter methods. What are `Consumer1` and `Consumer2` doing differently? And what separates `C` and `D` from `B`?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) is best fit for this problem. This will make it properly extensible, while encapsulating eventual `instanceof` calls into the consumer themselves.

To add to this. I don't think using `instanceof` is wrong. It just needs to be properly encapsulated, just like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [acyclic visitor pattern](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2012/12/the-acyclic-visitor-pattern.html). It allows extensions to the hierarchy without necessarily impacting all the visitors (only the ones that need to visit all objects, which don't seem to be present in your design).

Alternatively, I think it's not a problem to have the type checks in the consumer themselves, since they'll be concerned with checking only the types that they work with (not that different from the acyclic visitors). Then you could either dispatch the `I`s to all consumers and only the ones that really care about the runtime type will do anything with them, or you could do it in a chain of responsibility style, as already suggested in the comments by John Cartwright.

Answer (score 0):

Why is consumers not able to do their work with just I interface? Consumers should require instances of I, not rely on specifics of B,C or D.